# Flurry test push notification comes, but campain notification does not come

Tags: java, flurry

Flurry's testPush is working fine. However, when I run start campain, I get no notification
The error Invalid Registration is listed in the Campaign Analytics Dashboard

InvalidRegistration:
Check the format of the registration token you pass to the server.
Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives
from registering with FCM. Do not truncate or add additional characters.

Execution procedure

1. Save Target, Delivery, Goal Event (Optional), etc. with the default settings
2. Run start campain of Authorize App (test push notification is coming)
   → No notification
   Campaign Analytics Dashboard shows 1 for Fail
   1 is displayed in the Invalid Registration column

Please tell me how to deal with these errors.

Reference web page
https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/push/testpush/troubleshooting/

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using? And when testing, do you test with the IDFA/IDFV or the token?

Comment: This issue is occurring on Android devices.
When test push　I am testing by getting a push token.


Here is the sdk version you are using.


'com.flurry.android: ads: 12.7.0'

'com.flurry.android: analytics: 12.7.0'

'com.flurry.android: marketing: 12.7.0'

'com.google.firebase: firebase-core: 17.5.0'

'com.google.firebase: firebase-messaging: 20.2.4'

Comment: @Flurry Analytics Support　
Could you give me this answer by 1/22?

Comment: I used your code in a test app, but could not replicate the error. Can you write our support at support@flurry.com with the app's api key, and the date/time of the test push failure? We'll investigate